# Can we use lineinfile module to add new lines in Ansible based on matching a Regexp?

Tags: ansible

Basically, I have a text file that includes interface information (i.e interface gigabit0/1/2, interface gigabit0/2/3). I need to add an additional block after each interface command. It has to look as below:-

```
interface gigabit0/1/2
shutdown
!
interface gigabit0/2/3
shutdown
!
```

I have used an already existing "lineinfile" module to match the regex and add a new line once matched.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Ansible insert
      lineinfile:
        path: ./ha.txt
        line: |
              shutdown
              !
        insertafter: interface?\s[a-z]\w*/[0-9]/[0-9]
        state: present
      with_lines: cat ha.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#replace-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression). The play below

```
tasks:
  - replace:
      path: ha.txt
      regexp: '(interface?\s[a-z]\w*/[0-9]/[0-9])'
      replace: |-
               \1
               shutdown
               !
```

with the file

```
> cat ha.txt
interface gigabit0/1/2
interface gigabit0/2/3
```

gives:

```
> cat ha.txt
interface gigabit0/1/2
shutdown
!
interface gigabit0/2/3
shutdown
!
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of nitpicking here: in both the original and the excellent by Vladimir, the regexp could lose the `?` character after `interface`:

```
regexp: '(interface\s[a-z]\w*/[0-9]/[0-9])'
```

That `?` as-is means the `e` char in `interface` is optional, which does not make much sense.